# Test fails when using shorthand operator to determine true or false

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have this unit test which is working fine if I literally return true or false but does not work if I use a shorthand to determine if it is true or false.

Suppose I have this function `isMatched` where I take in a value to check it with a regex to determine if it matches or not and if it does, then return true, else return false.

```
function isMatched(value) {

  const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/;

  if (!value || !value.match(regex)){
    return false;
  }

  return true;

}
```

So I'm testing this function with this test spec:

```
it('should return true with correct value', () => {

    const matched = isMatched('bOomBoom 1');

    console.log(matched); // returns true

    expect(matched).toBe(true);

});
```

This passes the test perfectly but if I remove the if block from `isMatched` function and replace it with `return value && value.match(regex)`, then the test fails and the log shows an array of value, index, input and groups.

What is this sorcery?

Comment: Do you know what the match method returns? The difference between `true` and truth-y? Probably you want `!!value.match(regex)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh crap, doesn't it return a boolean? I thought it does. So if I want to use the shorthand, I have to use !! at the beginning?

Comment: No, _as you can see_ it returns an array (which if non-empty is truth-y, but _not actually `true`_).

Comment: Didn't your test case show what the error was? I know mine gives the wrong value when the test fails.

Comment: @epascarello yes it did, I got confused.

Comment: Okay if I use this `return value && !!value.match(regex)` then the test above passes but fails if I pass a value which wouldn't match. Returns empty string. Any other shorthand to achieve this? Also just tried with .test. Returns empty string for false test

Comment: `value` isn't a boolean, too. Why would you expect your shorthand to return a boolean? `return !!(value && value.match(regex));`

Comment: @jabaa It worked now. Thanks a lot guys. Who wants to post the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> Logical AND (`&&`) evaluates operands from left to right, returning immediately with the value of the first falsy operand it encounters; if all values are truthy, the value of the last operand is returned.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#description)

The expression

```
value && value.match(regex)
```

has two possible outputs:

- `value` is truthy -> return `value.match(regex)`
- `value` is falsy -> return `value`

You have to convert the result to a boolean for your test. One way is to negate the result twice:

```
!!(value && value.match(regex))
```